# Argument 2 passed to Spatie\Searchable\SearchResult::__construct() must be of the type string, null given

Tags: laravel, laravel-searchable

im using [spatie/laravel-searchable](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-searchable) for my website.
it works very well in this function:

```
  public function index(Request $request)
  {
    $results = (new Search())
    ->registerModel(Product::class, 'name', 'price','barcode')
    ->registerModel(Category::class, 'name')
    ->registerModel(Catalog::class, 'name')
    ->registerModel(Color::class, 'fatitle','entitle')
    ->search($request->input('query'));
    return response()->json($results);
  }
```

but in some words(like:cu006), i have this error:

```
Argument 2 passed to Spatie\Searchable\SearchResult::__construct() must be of the type string, null given
vendor/spatie/laravel-searchable/src/SearchResult.php:19
public function __construct(Searchable $searchable, string $title, ?string $url = null)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your model, when you create the `getSearchResult` function

```
 public function getSearchResult(): SearchResult
 {
     return new \Spatie\Searchable\SearchResult(
        $this,
        $this->title
     );
 }
```

If you write `$this->title` you need to make sure that your model actually contains the `title` field, if it doesn't it'll give you that error.

Comment: That saved me!! thanks alot. do you know if there is any way show other fields under title? like description to create a proper search result page

Comment: @stoneshak there might be but I'm not sure, I wrote this answer when I came across the problem myself and started debugging, you'd need to try things out and see, or create another question

Answer (score 1):

```
public function getSearchResult(): SearchResult
{
    $companySlug = currentCompanySlug();

    $url = url('/'.$companySlug.'/'.config('global-search- url.'.class_basename($this)));
    $null = null;
    return new SearchResult($this, $this->field_name ?:$null, $url);
}
```

please add in your model.